# Unable to get the desired output for mask detection

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook, computer-vision, svm

I am working on a mini project of Face mask detection using python and Open-cv library, I have written a correct code but still while running the code to generate real time output its throwing a lot error. Below is the code to generate the output via webcam. Please help me through this error.

```
haar_data = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
data = []
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX
while True:
    flag, img = capture.read()
    if flag:
        faces = haar_data.detectMultiScale(img)
        for x,y,w,h in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y), (x+w, y+h), (255,0,255), 4)
            face = img[y:y+h, x:x+h, :]
            face = cv2.resize(face, (50,50))
            face = face.reshape(1,-1)
            pred = svm.predict(face)[0]
            n = names[int(pred)]
            cv2.putText(img, n, (x,y), font, 1, (244,250,250), 2)
            print(n)
        cv2.imshow('result',img)
        if cv2.waitKey(2) == 27:
            break
capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Below is the error its showing and also the video is getting stuck while getting an output and I had to close the program forcefully due to which the kernel is dying.
This project is done in jupyter notebook. I even got an accuracy score of 91% but unable to get the output.

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-ad01d854464f> in <module>
----> 1 haar_data = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
      2 capture = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
      3 data = []
      4 font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX
      5 while True:

NameError: name 'cv2' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you imported OpenCV library?

```
import cv2
```

Comment: Ok, then check if the library is installed, you can use `pip list` command.

If not, install it with pip or conda (it depends what you are using).

Furthermore, If you use a virtual env (like Conda or Virtualenv) check if the notebook is launched from that environment.

Comment: I have checked and tried one more time but now its throwing a different error stating svm is not defined, even though I have defined itNameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-91fa20ec4154> in <module>
     11             face = cv2.resize(face, (50,50))
     12             face = face.reshape(1,-1)
---> 13             pred = svm.predict(face)[0]
     14             n = names[int(pred)]
     15             cv2.putText(img, n, (x,y), font, 1, (244,250,250), 2)

NameError: name 'svm' is not defined

Comment: When you get something like 'NameError: name '...' is not defined', it means that the module is not visible to the python interpreter (the library has not been installed or is not found). Check with `pip list` that scikit-learn is already installed or use `pip install -U scikit-learn`.

Tip: you can try using Colab (https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/intro.ipynb?utm_source=scs-index) instead of Jupyter. In Google Colaboratory (Colab) many libraries are already pre-installed and you shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: Please could you help me out with the project coz every now and then I am getting error in the output code. I am new in this project, so if you agree then I can send the whole code to you and you can check what's wrong.